# KnockoutJs bind JSON obj to nested ViewModel and dont ignore ViewModel not corresponding properties to JSON obj and keep VM functions

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I define a nested viewmodel in KnockoutJs, Like this:

```
function Person() {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable("");
    self.someProp = ko.observable(false);
    self.someFunc = function() {
        self.someProp(false);
    };    
}

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.someData = ko.observableArray([new Person()]);

    self.loadPersonsData = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/GetAllPersons',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({"catId": selectedCategoryId }),
            success: function (response) {
                self.someData(response.someData);                                       
            }
    });
}
```

Required data get from ajax, then `title` property of `Person` fill from JSON object, but `someProp` property dont exist in JSON object returned from server. 
And then apply bindings :

```
var vm;
$(function() {
    vm = new viewModel();    
    vm.loadPersonsData();    
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Binding view to html elements in this way:

```
<section data-bind="foreach: someData">
    .
    .
    .
    <button data-bind="click: function(data, event) {  $data.someFunc(); event.stopPropagation(); }" type="button">other</button>
</section>
```

When click to button the below error message was shown:

> TypeError: $data.someFunc is not a function

Then i change codes before apply bindings:

```
vm = new viewModel();    
vm.loadPersonsData();
$.each(vm.someData() , function(i, val) {         
    self.someProp = ko.observable(false);
    self.someFunc = function() {
        self.someProp(false);
    };    
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

By using this code top error not shown and app work fine. by calling `vm.loadPersonsData();` in another function or event, data successfully get from server and bind to html. But by clicking on the button top error message was shown.

Please tell me that how to fix this bug?
regards

Comment: In your AJAX call, you completely replace the contents of `self.someData`. It looks like you want to replace some data, but keep `someFunc`. You might look at ko.mapping for that. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Your callback

```
success: function (response) {
    self.someData(response.someData);                                       
}
```

isn't inflating Person objects, it's appending the data, not an instance of Person

Comment: Ok, you've correctly pointed out the problem, now if you would mention the solution, that would be great.

Comment: instead of adding response.someData to self.someData, you want a person.  `self.someData(Person())`. This would be an empty person with no data, you'd have to set that up as well.

Comment: I know the reponse, I'm just hinting at: *if you edited your answer with a function that would actually **show** the code required to have it working as OP expected, I would consider voting up your answer instead of adding mine*. Right now your answer says: "here's the problem, find out the rest". It's clear that OP needs a better understanding of OOP in JS.